# Flutter navigation best practices for global/app level state changes

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

**Problem statement:**

I have a flutter app which contains 3 different loaders. Loaders as in widgets whose whole purpose is to just route traffic based on certain criteria.The three loaders watches(ref.watch) 3 different riverpod async providers and whenever state change happens they rebuild aka reroute.

Let's say the three loader widgets I have are called A,B and C and each one of them just uses return statement like "return D()" to route the traffic. They don't really use the Navigator. So post these initial routing the widget tree happens to be in a proper hierarchical order like MaterialApp-->A-->B-->-->C-->D .

Now when I encounter button clicks or similar actions that warrants the use push/pushNamed Navigator actions it forms a separate route as it get pushed to the top of the stack beneath my MaterialApp like two routes for example MaterialApp--->E and MaterialApp-->A-->B-->C-->D

I understand this is the expected behaviour but is there a way to use Navigator and push the new widgets beneath my entire widget tree at given point in time? More like a parent-child structure.

The need for this is that my loaders are used for checking network access and corresponding actions if no network and for listening to auth and subscription changes. So, We want these 3 loaders to be in the top of the stack at all times to respond to state changes.